# Particles are not visible when rendered (ver. 2.83.5)

Tags: rendering, particles

Sprinkles particles are missing when rendered

- **Camera icon** ON
- Properties - Particles - Render - **Show Emitter** checked

[image]

File -

[image]

I saw a lot of similar topics here but couldn't find the right solution :(
Please, help me to figure out the problem

Comment: I came to try and help, but wow, I didn't even know you could do that. Hope it gets well. That's a cool looking doughnut BTW :D

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Modifier Properties]

This button was not enabled on your file, enabling it fixes this, it just controls whether the particles are on during rendering, it might look a bit different for you, but it should still be a camera in the particles section.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally did it <3

Comment: No problem, I am doing the blender guru doughnut as well, almost finished, good luck with yours it looks great so far :)